# composer update: Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, composer-php, laravel-5.6

I'm trying to upgrade from laravel 5.5 to 5.6. I've been using the [upgrade guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/upgrade) for this.

First, I tried updating `laravel/framework` to `5.6.*` and `phpunit/phpunit` to `~7.0`.

This yields an error `Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.`

I understand what this means, but the error log is really hard to parse, and I've been trying for a few hours now to change the `composer.json` file to a installable set of packages.
I haven't managed to fix this myself, so I come to you. Maybe some of you guys actually like fixing these problems...

So, my current `composer.json`, in all its glory:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.1",
        "laravel/framework": "5.6.*",
        "jenssegers/rollbar": "^1.4",
        "doctrine/dbal": "~2.3",
        "sensiolabs/security-checker": "^3.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0",
        "mandrill/mandrill": "1.0.*",
        "lcobucci/jwt" : "^3.1",
        "predis/predis": "~1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~7.0",
        "phpspec/phpspec": "~4.0",
        "laravel/homestead" : "~4.0",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "3.1.*",
        "symfony/css-selector": "3.1.*",
        "filp/whoops": "~2.0"
    }
}
```

And the current error:

```
➔ composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.15
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.14
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/process v4.0.7
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.13
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/process v4.0.6
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/process v4.0.5
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/process v4.0.4
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/process v4.0.3
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/process v4.0.2
    - Installation request for laravel/homestead ~4.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/homestead[v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5].
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/process v4.0.1
    - laravel/framework v5.6.0 requires symfony/process ~4.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/process[v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7].
    - laravel/framework v5.6.1 requires symfony/process ~4.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/process[v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7].
    - laravel/framework v5.6.10 requires symfony/process ~4.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/process[v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7].
    - laravel/framework v5.6.11 requires symfony/process ~4.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/process[v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7].
    - laravel/framework v5.6.12 requires symfony/process ~4.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/process[v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7].
    - laravel/framework v5.6.2 requires symfony/process ~4.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/process[v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7].
    - laravel/framework v5.6.3 requires symfony/process ~4.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/process[v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7].
    - laravel/framework v5.6.4 requires symfony/process ~4.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/process[v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7].
    - laravel/framework v5.6.5 requires symfony/process ~4.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/process[v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7].
    - laravel/framework v5.6.6 requires symfony/process ~4.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/process[v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7].
    - laravel/framework v5.6.7 requires symfony/process ~4.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/process[v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7].
    - laravel/framework v5.6.8 requires symfony/process ~4.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/process[v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7].
    - laravel/framework v5.6.9 requires symfony/process ~4.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/process[v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7].
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/process v4.0.0
    - Installation request for laravel/framework 5.6.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.2, v5.6.3, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9].
```

I really hope someone is able to decipher what composer means here. I would love to be able to do this myself as well, but it seems all the other solutions of this same question are really specifically for **that** `composer.json` only, and not a general answer..

Comment: From that guide: "_Laravel 5.6 requires PHP 7.1.3 or higher._" See if changing `"php": ">=7.1",` to `"php": "^7.1.3",` helps

Comment: Try to add `symfony/process` with `composer require symfony/process`

Comment: Also from that guide: "_All of the underlying Symfony components used by Laravel have been upgraded to the Symfony ~4.0 release series._" You should probably update all Symfony components to 4

Comment: `rm -rf ./vendor & composer update` if that still throws up you need to upgrade PHP to 7.1.14.

Comment: Trying these suggestions now. Thanks, guys, I'm a bit ashamed. How did I not see that?!

Comment: I guess you can add `"symfony/process": "^4.0"` before the `"laravel/framework": "5.6.*",` to your `require` and see what happens

Comment: Thanks everyone! I now have a correct composer.json. For future people with headaches: I updated `php` to `^7.1.3`, `sensiolabs/security-checker` to `^4.1`, `phpspec` to `~4.0`, `laravel/homestead` to `~7.3`, `symfony/dom-crawler` and `symfony/css-selector` to `^4.0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this situation, I had to do the following:

- I updated `php` to `^7.1.3`
- `sensiolabs/security-checker` to `^4.1`
- `phpspec` to `~4.0`
- `laravel/homestead` to `~7.3`
- `symfony/dom-crawler` and `symfony/css-selector` to `^4.0`
- Remove references to `composer optimize` as that's now removed
- Stop using `configureMonologUsing(...)` and create a custom logger class for Rollbar.

Thanks for all the help in the comments!